# Set page for PDF to open to

Tags: pdf, preview

In Adobe Acrobat (2019) you can set the page that appears when you open the PDF in the File > Properties > Initial View (tab). Preview always opens the document to page 1. Adobe Acrobat Mac/Win will open the document on the specified page. Does Preview support this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

No. Preview does not respect the PDF `Initial View` metadata. Other Readers, such as Skim and PDFPen Pro, also do not. Instead, all of these apps open at page 1 and then remember the last page viewed for the next time the document is opened. Foxit Reader does respect the Initial View.

Your best solution is to provide a Table of Contents (*aka* Bookmarks, Outlines), so that users can easily click to the desired page.

It's worth noting that Preview's own 'Bookmarks' are not PDF-standard, and will not be displayed by any other PDF Viewer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes indirectly. Go to the page you wish to open your file to next time you open it in Preview. Once there go to the File menu and select save. Then close the file. Next time you open the file in Preview it will open to that spot.

Comment: Thanks but this won't solve my issue. We have a PDF with different forms that a person may want to use. This is available for download on our website. For some reason, before we took over this, they put all the forms in one PDF (along with instructions, regulations, disclaimers, etc.) and created different versions of the PDF that opened on different pages. I guess they did that so they could guarantee that a person would always have all the forms. It work in Acrobat, Chrome, Edge and a couple of other PDF reader I have tried. May have to revisit this and make 3 different PDFs.

Comment: That does not work when you move the PDF to another computer. Preview remembers the last page viewed (even without saving) and stores that info in the User Library, not in the PDF itself.